# Where can i find IOS and Android system sounds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building a React Native app with Expo and i am trying to play keyboard type sound on a button press

Where can I find these mp3 files?

Answer (score -2):

You have many websites for it. I would download it from an mp3 youtube downloader

Comment: i searched a lot of websites and did not find the right sound

Comment: If you think there are many websites for it - you can share them with @Harel.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNx-WghsW_U&list=PLBlocmrrFygYrwDGgBkTo9Ht0Cks5Di1_

Comment: This is not what he asked for, please read @Harel 's question again.

Comment: https://picturetosound.com/en/a/26/iphone-typing-on-keyboard